# Adjusting jQuery code that takes data from select input and puts it into DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I already have the code ready but my limited jQuery skills, if any, can't help me figure out why the output I want can't be achieved.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
 $('#property_types option').slice(1).each(
 function(){
var text = $(this).text(),
    outputTo = $('#output'),
    div = $('<div />', {'class' : text}).text(text),
    href = $('<a />', {'href' : '#', 'onclick' : 'go'+text+'();'}).prependTo(div),
    img = $('<img />', {'src' : 'images/'+text+'.png', 'style' : 'vertical-align:middle;padding-right:5px', 'width' : '35'}).prependTo(href);
div.appendTo(outputTo);
 });
```

and here's the output it currently gives:

```
 <div id="output">
 <div class="Apartment">
 <a href="#" onclick="goApartment();">
 <img src="images/Apartment.png" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 5px; width: 35px;">
 </a>
 Apartment
 </div>
```

The problem is, the text AKA "Apartment" is being left out of the link. how can I fix this without hurting the current functions of the code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#property_types option').slice(1).each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text(),
    outputTo = $('#output'),
    div = $('<div />', {'class' : text});
    href = $('<a />', {'href' : '#', 'onclick' : 'go'+text+'();'}).text(text).prependTo(div),
    img = $('<img />', {'src' : 'images/'+text+'.png', 'style' : 'vertical-align:middle;padding-right:5px', 'width' : '35'}).prependTo(href);
    div.appendTo(outputTo);
 });
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! You rock!!